# Joomla : Hide third lavel navigation without disabling from menu

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have a site which is developed in Joomla version 1.5.9. I want to hide third and onwards level drop down menu without deactivatinf the **Published** button from admin area.
Actually, I am using Xmap plugin. If I am deactivating from menu section, then it is also not showing in Site map.

For example,

http://jupiterpumpandwell.vidushiinfotech.info/services/water-treatment-services/iron-removal-systems.html

I don't want to show above page in main navigation. But ,I want to show in sitemap.

Is there is any function by using this, we can hide only the third level menu from main navigation, not from the sitemap.

If there is anything available, please let me know.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

Log to backend and go to module manager. Open module of your menu, and on the right side there is option `End Level`. Choose level where you want to stop menu rendering. In your case it would be 2

Comment: Thanks Mark for reply. I searched for above option in Menu Module. But, I didn't find. I am using Joomla old version 1.5.9.
Can you explain in details?

Comment: @NeerajPrasad It is the same in new and old Joomla. Log to backend, go to Extensions -> Module Manager, find your menu module (it's type is mod_mainmenu) and follow steps I wrote

Comment: 1) You use custom extension `mod_transmenu` which doesn't have that option - you have to add it yourself. 2) Your website needs urgent update, as it has many vulerabilities due to lack of updates 3) I really hope username and pass you left here were only for test, please change them and delete your comment